# How to sort object property in list by first two characters then alpha

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, generics

I have a list of objects. The objects are insurance policies. Well, the first part of every policy number is alpha charater, then all numeric. I need to sort all policies with policy number starting with CA first in the list, then by alpha numeric after that. For example, if I have three policies, AB10001, CA20001, CA20003, the order should be all "CA" first, then sort rest like below:`enter code here`

```
CA20001
CA20003
AB10001
```

What is throwing me off, as I understand regular sorts, is how to get all CA first since they do not apply to alpha order.  I think possibly, pull all of the CA prefixed policy names into a new list, then order those by numeric. Then sort the leftovers in a second list. Then append the second list to the "CA" sorted list if that makes sense. There must be a cleaner way though using lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
const string CAHeader = "CA";

IEnumerable<string> sorted = 
  list.OrderBy(s => s.StartsWith(CAHeader) ? s.Substring(CAHeader.Length) : s);
```

Comment: That will work with the specific data, but if there could be a value like "100" in there that would come before the strings that start with "CA".

Comment: @juharr True but the OP wrote 'Well, the first part of every policy number is alpha charater, then all numeric' I don't see any reason to over engineer the thing here

Comment: That is one rule I can rely on being true is index(0,2) always character.

Comment: If you encapsulate the policy number in its own class then that rule becomes easier to enforce. You can make it literally impossible to create an invalid policy number.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with something like.

```
var list = new List<string> { "AB10001", "CA20003", "CA20001" };

var ordered = list.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartsWith("CA")).ThenBy(s => s);

foreach(var o in ordered) Console.WriteLine(o);
```

which outputs

> CA20001
>
> CA20003
>
> AB10001

Basically you first order everything by whether or not it begins with "CA" then by the actual string value.  You have to use descending because `false` is considered to be less than `true`.

Comment: I can't believe `linq` *actually* has a `.ThenBy()` method - learn something new every day!

Comment: @levelonehuman `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` actually return a `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>` and `TheyBy` and `ThenByDescending` are defined as extension methods on that interface.  It basically keeps track of the set of orderings.

Answer (score 0):

Implement IComparer and put custom logic in Compare.

Comment: This sounds like it could be the right thing to do, but an example of this with some explanation would make for a far better answer. As it stands, this should probably just be a comment.

Comment: I have never used IComparer before, I will look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `IComparer` implementation. It's about 1200% more lines of code than juharr's solution. But it could be handy in certain scenarios that I haven't thought of yet.

The comparer:

```
public class PolicyComparer : IComparer<Policy>
{
    public static PolicyComparer Instance { get; } = new PolicyComparer();

    public int Compare(Policy x, Policy y)
    {
        return x.PolicyNumber.StartsWith("CA") ^ y.PolicyNumber.StartsWith("CA") 
            ? (x.PolicyNumber.StartsWith("CA") ? -1 : 1)
            : string.Compare(x.PolicyNumber, y.PolicyNumber, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

An extension for sorting:

```
public static class PolicyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Policy> Sort(this IEnumerable<Policy> unsortedPolicies)
    {
        var sorted = new List<Policy>(unsortedPolicies);
        sorted.Sort(PolicyComparer.Instance);
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

The `Policy` class I used for testing:

```
public class Policy
{
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

A unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void PoliciesAreSortedByCAfirst()
    {
        var unsorted = new Policy[]
        {
            new Policy {PolicyNumber = "AB10001"},
            new Policy {PolicyNumber = "CA20003"},
            new Policy {PolicyNumber = "CA20001"}
        };

        var sorted = unsorted.Sort();

        var expectedOrder = new string[] {"CA20001", "CA20003", "AB10001"};
        Assert.IsTrue(expectedOrder.SequenceEqual(sorted.Select(policy=>policy.PolicyNumber)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this wrong. What needs to be sortable isn't the policy. It's the policy *number*. It's actually not a bad idea to declare the policy number as a separate class rather than using a string. The reason is that you can "hide" its implementation. Maybe at some point a policy "number" becomes a combination of two fields.

That makes even more sense because the policy number has its own logic that has nothing to do with `Policy`. It has a custom sort order. It probably has its own rules for validation. If it's just a string attached to a `Policy` then `Policy` has to own all that. And it's not unrealistic that you might want to put a policy number on something that isn't itself a policy, like a claim against a policy. (This is the sort of ID that probably shows up everywhere.)

Here's a solution from that angle:

```
public class PolicyNumber : IComparable
{
    private readonly string _number;

    public PolicyNumber(string number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as PolicyNumber;
        if (other == null) return 0;
        return _number.StartsWith("CA") ^ other._number.StartsWith("CA")
            ? (_number.StartsWith("CA") ? -1 : 1)
            : string.Compare(_number, other._number, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _number;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as PolicyNumber;
        return other != null && string.Equals(_number, other._number);
    }

    protected bool Equals(PolicyNumber other)
    {
        return string.Equals(_number, other._number);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (_number != null ? _number.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

And the unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void PoliciesAreSortedByCAfirst()
    {
        var unsorted = new Policy[]
        {
            new Policy{Number = new PolicyNumber("AB10001")},
            new Policy{Number = new PolicyNumber("CA20003")},
            new Policy{Number = new PolicyNumber("CA20001")}
        };

        var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(policy => policy.Number);
        var expectedOrder = new Policy[]
        {
            unsorted[2], unsorted[1], unsorted[0]
        };
        Assert.IsTrue(expectedOrder.SequenceEqual(sorted));
    }
}
```

Notice how that allows `PolicyNumber` to "own" its own logic. Classes that use it just sort it without knowing or caring how it is sorted. And you can still compare it for equality just like a string.

The unit test shows how easy that is to use. Instead of asking something to sort it for you, you just sort it. If it's a `Policy` with a policy number you can sort it by the policy number or by something else.